# Laravel conditional order by relation column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I got two models:

Player & Game

Now every game has two relations, homePlayer: BelongsTo(Player) & awayPlayer: BelongsTo(Player). This means in my database a game looks like this:

Game:

- id
- home_player_id
- away_player_id
- score
- ...

Now on the player's profile i have a table which displays all of his games. I'd like to now be able to sort by opponent, so the games which are played against the same opponents are "grouped".

My problem now is, the opponent might sometimes be the home, sometimes be the away player. That means i can't simply sort by away_player, i somehow have to sort by the opponents id, which sometimes might be the home_player_id and sometimes the away_player_id.

Any pointers on how i could solve that problem?

```
class Game extends Model {
  protected $with = ['homePlayer', 'awayPlayer'];
  public function homePlayer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'home_player_id');
  }
  public function awayPlayer(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'away_player_id');
  }
}
```

Comment: home and away player have the same model I guess like user/gamer, right? you need to fetch the players based on their ID and group their games. then list if they were at home or away.

Comment: Yes home and away players are the same model. The problem with grouping in the frontend is that i also have pagination.. :( So that is not an option then right?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a closure to the `groupBy` in eloquent. So you can add your condition there.

First add your condition in your model:

```php
 public function filter(Player $player)
    {
        if ($this->homePlayer->id === $player->id) {
            return $this->awayPlayer;
        }
        if ($this->awayPlayer->id === $player->id) {
            return $this->homePlayer;
        }   
    }
```

And then use the condition to get group results:

```php
$games->groupBy(function ($game) use ($player) {
  return $game->filter($player)->id;
});
```